# HTML table cells width

Tags: css, html, user-interface, html-table

I'm trying to implement the following table layout in HTML

[image]

Table of 100% width has three columns. Left and right column content is floated to left and right accordingly. Left and right columns should allocate minimum viable space by their widest child, where as middle column allocates the remaining space. How do I define such a table with HTML5 and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #af3;
}

table th, 
table td {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table tr td:first-of-type,
table tr th:first-of-type,
table tr td:first-of-type,
table tr th:last-of-type  {
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
     <tr>
      <th>Element</th>
      <th>Element</th>
      <th>Element</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Element</td>
      <td>Element</td>
      <td>Element</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Element</td>
      <td>Element</td>
      <td>Element</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Element</td>
      <td>Element</td>
      <td>Element</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>Element</td>
      <td>Element</td>
      <td>Element</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="left">left</div>
  <div class="middle">middle</div>
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```

```
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: #fff;
}

.left {
  flex: none;
  background: #111;
}

.right {
  flex: none;
  background: #111;
}

.middle {
  flex: auto;
  background: #66ccff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a w3school tutorial [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_three_columns.asp) on how to do something that is very similar to what you are trying to do, I adapted it and made a codepen out of it [Codepen](https://codepen.io/darrow8/pen/eaWrQL).

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="leftclm" class="column" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Column 1</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
  <div id="rightclm" class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
    <h2>Column 3</h2>
    <p>Some text..</p>
  </div>
</div>



    * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create three equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
}
#rightclm{
  width: 20%;
}
#leftclm{
  width: 20%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```